# JavaScript/jQuery: Animated Cursor/Light Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visibility

Recently, I found an SVG with an animated cursor element (like the kind of cursor you see when you're typing text on a screen, like I am now). The JavaScript behind this basically **switches the visibility of the target element between on and off**. The "cursor" element was the only part of the SVG file that the JavaScript affected. I've found that it can target HTML document objects, too.

Here's the original **JavaScript**, with `id="cursor"` (`#cursor`) marking the target element:

```
var visible = true;
setInterval(function () {
    document.querySelector('#cursor').style.opacity = visible ? 0 : 1;
    visible = !visible;
}, 550);
```

What I want to do is alter this code to make it fade in and out. The resulting effect would be like this:

1. Fade in quickly (**250** ms)
2. Stay visible for less than half a second (**500** ms)
3. Fade out (**250** ms)
4. Repeat 1.~3.

In other words, steps 1 through 3 would all take place in **one second, *every* second**.

The question I have about this is: **how do I do this in either JavaScript or jQuery?**

(P.S.: **is there a jQuery equivalent to the above code?**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery, you could do the following

```
setInterval(function () {
    $("#cursor").fadeIn(500, function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(500);
    });
}, 1000);
```

Using an interval like you mentioned to start the fade in (utilizing jQuery functions). Passing a callback to fade back out. You can mess with the timing to fit your feel

Comment: Thanks. Here's the base version of what I turned it into: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbishop017/HgF4z/